# DataGridView CheckBox Functionality Not Working

Tags: c#, datagridview, sql-server-2008r2-express

I have a DataGridView that has CheckBox Field. I am trying to update Checkbox values in database. But it's giving me this Error. I already implement method `ufGview_DataError` with value `e.Cancel = true`. I am interested to store 0 when it will be Checked and 1 when it will be Unchecked. Sometimes it is updating values but most of the time not doing anything. I am using C# with Sql Server 2008 R2 Express Edition

Here is method that i am using to update database values

```
 if (e.ColumnIndex == 3)
 {
    if (ufGview.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Column2"].Value != null)
     {
        bool a = Convert.ToBoolean(ufGview.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Column2"].Value);
        int i;
        if (a == true)
        {
           i = 0;
         }
         else
         {
           i = 1;
         }
         UpdatePermissions(ufGview.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Column1"].Value.ToString(), i);
     }
 }
```

Here is Method of `UpdatePermissions`

```
  private void UpdatePermissions(string p, int a)
    {
        CheckConnectionStatus();
        try
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("Update FamilyMembers Set status=@status where Id=@Id", sqlConnection);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", a);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", p);
            sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

            sqlConnection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exp.Message.ToString(), "Exception in UpdatePermissions");
        }
        finally
        {
            CheckConnectionStatus();
        }
    }
```

Please help me to fix this issue shown in Snapshot as well.

[image]

Comment: `if (e.ColumnIndex == 3)
 { --Try add this here. dgName.commitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    if (ufGview.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Column2"].Value != null)
     {`

Comment: @Muj nothing changed.. It is changing value in database to Checked Only

Comment: @Muj any update ?

Comment: check if `a` contains a value. Try to track if all your variable passing to you query is contains something, not null.